# Values not displayed on Axis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a plot between Dates and AED. I am able to draw the plot but there are no values shown on the x and y axis. Please help me with getting the values shown on the axis 
Dates is of Date type and AED is of numeric type.

My code for plotting the graph :

```
>dput(x$Date)
>structure(c(17805, 17806, 17807, 17808, 17809, 17811, 17812, 
17813, 17814, 17815, 17816, 17817, 17818, 17819, 17820, 17821, 
17822, 17823, 17824, 17825, 17826, 17827, 17828, 17829, 17830, 
17831, 17832, 17833, 17834, 17835), class = "Date")

>dput(x$AED)
>structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "1", "10", "101", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "4", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
"45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "5", "50", "51", "52", "53", "55", 
"57", "58", "59", "6", "60", "61", "65", "66", "68", "7", "73", 
"74", "77", "8", "80", "84", "86", "87", "9", "98", "A28"), class = "factor")

 >x <- d2[which(d2$User_ID=='Some_'),]
 >date = x$Date
 >AED = x$AED_Volume_Processed
 >plot(date,AED,main="Plot",xlab = "Days",ylab="Volume",pch=10)
```

I tried converting it to numeric but its still not working, basically the graph is not showing any values on axis

```
 > is.numeric(x$AED_Volume_Processed)
[1] TRUE
```

Thanks !

Comment: Could you show a sample of how you've created your data.frame? Current and expected output(s)?

Comment: Please share some sample data using `dput(head(date,10))` and `dput(head(AED,10))`.

Comment: Dates : "2018-10-01" "2018-10-02" "2018-10-03" "2018-10-04" "2018-10-05"
 AED : 26 87 22 74 74 57                   39 13 61 30 30 30    17       26 40 40 12 49    46 57

Blank indicates blank values

Comment: dont put them in the comment. put the output of `dput(Dates)` and `dput(AED)` in your question. this will make it much easier for people to help you

Comment: Thanks RAB and tushaR for guiding me

Comment: Your `AED` is a factor, not numeric, with only two values `""` and `"1"`. Try converting it to numeric before plotting. Do also consider what numeric value `""` should map to.